# Trouble with handling exceptions for repeated errors (python)

Tags: python, discord.py, try-except

I have a discord bot that responds to a message by answering in a random channel. Sometimes it will randomly select a channel it doesn't have permission to send messages in, and it will raise an error.

Here is how I have been handling this error:

```
try:
    if message.content == "!xd":
        guild = client.guilds[0]
        random_xd = random.choice(random_list)
        await random.choice(guild.text_channels).send(random_xd)
except discord.errors.Forbidden:
    print("\nsomething went wrong\n")
    if message.content == "!xd":
        guild = client.guilds[0]
        random_xd = random.choice(random_list)
        await random.choice(guild.text_channels).send(random_xd)
```

Sometimes the bot sends messages to a channel it doesn't have permissions in more than once. How do I make it run this block of code until it eventually sends a message?

Comment: I couldn't understand your question, does except block works well?

Comment: It works, but it only tries to send the message again once. If the bot tries to send the message to a channel it doesn't have permissions in more than 2 times, no message is sent and it raises an error. (If it randomly selects the same channel more than once it doesn't send a message)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your question well but I'll try to answer as I understand. At first, as I know that error handling doesn't work fine with `try-except` so you should use `on_command_error` event. Like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, discord.errors.Forbidden):
        if message.content == "!xd":
            guild = client.guilds[0]
            random_xd = random.choice(random_list)
            await random.choice(guild.text_channels).send(random_xd)
```

This must work for you.